# An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'Name'

Tags: c#

The line that beings `int temp = Convert`... is giving the error:

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'Name'

The surrounding code is:

```
String checkuser = "select count(*) from [UserRecord] where User Name= " +TextBoxUsername.Text + "";
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(checkuser, conn);
int temp = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar().ToString()); //error on this line 
if (temp == 1)
```

Can someone explain what is causing the error?

Comment: your query is bad.  To start, you need single quotes around your text.  But really you need to parameterize your query

Comment: Also you probably shouldn't have a space in `User Name`

Comment: Your code reminds me of [Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: ...Also if a name is searched that isn't in the database you'll throw an error

Comment: OP - @Jonesy and I barely kept your question from getting closed. Please use our edits as instruction on how to ask an "answerable" question.

Comment: must be in square bracket [user name] and i think data type is string so it must be in sin-gal equates `String checkuser = "select count(*) from [UserRecord] where [User Name]= '" +TextBoxUsername.Text + "'";`

Comment: @HighCore: LOL - Excellent link!

Answer (score 2):

You need to surround the username with single quotes.

```
String checkuser = "select count(*) from [UserRecord] where User Name= '" +TextBoxUsername.Text + "'";
```

Also, `User Name` shouldn't have a space in it, or needs `[]` around it.

Or better yet, use a [parameterized query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: i think User Name column also in square bracket `String checkuser = "select count(*) from [UserRecord] where [User Name]= '" +TextBoxUsername.Text + "'";`

Comment: @user3420762 I believe you are correct. Since it's wrong as written, I wasn't sure what it was supposed to be. Although using spaces in field names is a wretched practice to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your query.there is a space between User and Name for username.

"select count(*) from [UserRecord] where User Name= "

Answer (score 0):

You forget **'**

```
String checkuser = "select count(*) from [UserRecord] where User Name= '" +TextBoxUsername.Text + "'";
```